# Empty Module.symvers file when compiling a module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a custom kernel module (let's call it mod1) that I would like to export functions for use in other modules (let's call those mod2, etc...). When compiling the other modules, I get warning messages about undefined symbols (functions in mod1). Though everything should work fine after loading, I like to compile without warnings. I read that I should add the path to mod1's Module.symvers to `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS` However, I noticed that my Module.symvers file is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a MWE of a module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_INFO(version, "0.1");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Me");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int foo(int x) {
    return x;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(foo)
```

And a Makefile:

```
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

And me running make showing that Module.symvers is empty:

```
user@host:~/mwe$ make; [[ -s ./Module.symvers ]] || echo "File size is zero!"
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/build M=/home/user/mwe modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic'
File size is zero!
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and my search for answers has been fruitless thusfar.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Makefile is incorrect. Where is the name of the file you want to compile ? Change `test.o` to whatever your filename.

Makefile:

```
obj-m += test.o

all:
            make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
            make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Got it, I realize that my MWE is flawed - thanks! I have a Kbuild file in my real module that specifies this. Interestingly enough, adding "obj-m += testmod.o" to a Kbuild fixes the error in the MWE, but not in my real module. Time to figure out the differences.

Comment: I also realized that it might be a little silly to have both a Kbuild and Makefile for a small module, so I'm just using a Makefile now (similar to your example above)

Comment: glad! also note Kconfig is only required when you want to build the mod with the rest of the kernel code. A simple makefile have always worked for fairly large modules.